# Daedalus is crashing my system. What can I do?

Tags: wallet, daedalus

I have a problem with the Daedalus wallet crashing my system.
This happenes due to the Daedalus process increasing usage of RAM while trying to connect on startup. The problem started occuring some days ago and persists.
Windows error code is MEMORY_MANAGEMENT.

Didn't reinstall up to now, would be the next try if someone doesn't have another solution.
Thanks a lot!

My system: Windows 10, 8GB RAM, Ryzen 1200.

Comment: Do you have your seed phrase safely stored somewhere?

Comment: Do you have any other programs running at the same time as Daedalus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [recommended requirements](https://daedaluswallet.io/en/download/) for Daedalus include:

- 8 GB of RAM
- 15 GB of free drive space

Your graphics card will not matter here.

Other processes on your Windows machine will influence how much memory will be left for daedalus, potentially resulting in that MEMORY_MANAGEMENT error. Also run diagnostics on your RAM.
Running daedalus after a fresh restart with little memory allocated to other processes might inform the next steps. That could include a reinstallation of daedalus (make sure you got your wallet info), a windows cleanup/reinstallation, upgrading of RAM and/or move to a different operating system such as Linux.

Comment: Thanks, after clearing some space on my harddrive and starting Daedalus right after startup just worked - but still driving the workload on my RAM very close to the maximum. Hard on ressources. Maybe it's time to upgrade! >:)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Daedalus on a small business server, Windows 2012 and 8Gb RAM and nothing else running on the box. I don't run Daedalus continuously. It runs and synchronises, but only just: at peak the cardano-node process consumes nearly 6Gb on is own, with the other Daedalus processes consuming about 25Mb. The OS comes in at about 1.2Gb. I would say that on Windows it needs 10Gb minimum to have a bit of breathing space knowing how it can hog memory ...
I am at the beginning of my journey running cardano nodes and decided to give Daedalus a go on a Window box before moving to Linux.